# How to Migrate Magento2 store to localhost?

Tags: magento2, migration

I am trying to migrate an established Magento2 store from an EC2 server to work on my local developer environment.  I have the files downloaded in my root directory and and have backed-up the database and put the database into my new mysql database.  However, when I go to my localhost I get this...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. in /Users/jonathanhelvey/UpperLimitsSite/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php:112 Stack trace: #0 /Users/jonathanhelvey/UpperLimitsSite/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php(127): Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getById('1') #1 /Users/jonathanhelvey/UpperLimitsSite/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(181): Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getActiveStoreById('1') #2 /Users/jonathanhelvey/UpperLimitsSite/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(126): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getDefaultStoreById('1') #3 /Users/jonathanhelvey/UpperLimitsSite/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(160): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId() #4 /Users/jonathanhelvey/UpperLimitsSite/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Pr in /Users/jonathanhelvey/UpperLimitsSite/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php on line 112
```

Does anyone know the right steps to migrate a Magento2 store to localhost from development.  There is no version control.  The store also does have 3rd parties extensions.

Comment: This answer might be more helpful to you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/318625/7863

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.

[Blockquote](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189259/how-toconfigure-an-existing-magento-2-1-7-project-in-another-pc-and-database)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.You run query in your database step by step.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: perhaps you can explain what this ‘copy and paste’ answer is doing, to help us understand what the problem is and how it is resolving it?

Comment: so any reason default store id has been changed so above answer is set the default.